# Sum increasing every time I download the data

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a shopping cart and when I download the data from the database I sum the prices and display the total amount that the user has to pay. The problem that I'm facing is that when I open the app my Shopping cart is empty so the sum is zero after I add 1 2 3 items and go back to the shopping list and then I go back to the shopping cart when I open the shopping cart the sum is = sum *2 of the last sum I had and if I'm not wrong it due to the onDataChange since it takes the prices from the dataset and adds the prices to the variable sum but it's wrong since it did it one.

I'm new to Android so I can't understand why it's happening, Thank you in advance.
Example :

Empty cart : sum = 0
Add 2 item to cart : sum = 100
Go back to shopping list: sum still 100
Go back from shopping list to the shopping cart without adding anything to the list: sum is 200 now with the same 2 items.

CODE:

```
    package com.example.ipill;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.net.HttpCookie;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;


public class CartActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  OnRemoveItemClickListener{

    private TextView total;
    private ImageButton removeFromCartt;
    private Button pay;
    private RecyclerView mResultList2;
    private DatabaseReference mUserDatabase;
    int i=0;
    public static int Totalprice=0;
    private UsersAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<Users_get> array_data = new ArrayList<>();
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);
        mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Cart");

        total          = findViewById(R.id.TotalPrice);
        total.setText(0+"");
        removeFromCartt = findViewById(R.id.removeFromCart);
        mResultList2    = findViewById(R.id.cartList);
        pay            = findViewById(R.id.pay);

        mResultList2.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mResultList2.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


        // Attach a listener to read the data at our posts reference
        mUserDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {


            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                int flag=1;

                if (adapter == null) {
                    for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Users_get post = childSnapshot.getValue(Users_get.class);
                        array_data.add(new Users_get(post.getName(), post.getSurname(), post.getPrice(), childSnapshot.getKey()));
                        if(array_data!=null){
                            getTotalPrice(post.getPrice(),flag);
                        }
                    }
                    total.setText(Integer.toString(Totalprice)+"");
                    setAdapter();
                } else {
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
            }

        });

        pay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(CartActivity.this,FirebaseSearch.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }


    private void setAdapter() {
        adapter = new UsersAdapter(array_data,CartActivity.this);
        mResultList2.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    public void getTotalPrice(Long price,int flag){
            if(flag==1)
            {
                Totalprice+=price;
            }
            if(flag==0)
            {
                Totalprice-=price;
            }

        System.out.println(Totalprice);
    }


    @Override
    public void onRemoveItemClicked(final int position) {
        int flag=0;
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Cart").child(array_data.get(position).getKey()).removeValue();
        getTotalPrice(array_data.get(position).getPrice(),flag);
        if(Totalprice!=0){
            total.setText(Integer.toString(Totalprice)+"");
        }
        else if(mResultList2==null){
            Totalprice=0;
            total.setText(0+"");
        }
        array_data.remove(position);
        adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(adapter !=null){
            adapter.removeListener();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It happens because you always do `TotalPrice +=` and never reset it.

Answer (score 0):

you are creating `static` variable

```
public static int Totalprice=0;
```

remove `static` keyword if you don't want it outside of activity

if you want it outside of activity you can reinitialise this variable into `onCreate()` to 0

```
Totalprice=0;
```